# border still shows, why?

Tags: html, css

Im having a weird issue on a table... I've set the border to be 0 in the css, i've set the border-color to be transparent, however, in the browser, it still shows a border on the top and on the left, which doesnt make any sense...

The table looks like `<table cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;" id="gvTransactions" pagersettings="" rules="all" class="transaction-posts">`

And the css looks like:

```
table.transaction-posts, table#gvTransactions {
  border: 0 none transparent !important;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

As you can see, it still outputs a black border on the top, left and in every row, even though i've set the border to be 0...

[image]

Comment: Open developer tools in your web browser (Firefox requires Firebug add-on), inspect your table (and optionaly it's inner elements) and check which one defines the border.

Comment: have you styled `tr` / `td` / `th`?

Comment: Cells and Rows have separate borders. You need to address them, too.

Comment: On the tr and td, i've set a border-bottom:1px solid #ccc, so it's not that...

Answer (score 0):

In the table tag...add border="0"...if that doesn't work then check if any of the css is over-riding it, also post your code in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML attribute `rules="all"` in the `table` tag causes borders to be drawn on all sides of all cells. The HTML 4.01 spec says this somewhat vaguely, but this is how browsers interpret it. So if you don’t want any borders, remove that attribute.

If you want to have some of the borders but not all, you need to set them suitably. For example, if the border on the very top and on the very left is the problem (this is one interpretation of the question asked), then set

```
table#gvTransactions tr:first-child th, table#gvTransactions tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}
table#gvTransactions th:first-child, table#gvTransactions td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
```

The first rule removes the top border of any cell in the first row. The second one removes the left border of any cell that is the first child of its parent, i.e. of the cells in the first column.